# Writing foreign key value into belongs_to model after create Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have a basic problem with a **has_one** and **belongs_to** association. I have two models: `StudentRegistration` and `User` that look like the following:

```
class StudentRegistration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one student_registration
end
```

The idea is that a student gets registered and then later a User account can be created.  My problem is that I'm storing the foreign key `user_id` in the `student_registration` table and I only know this once the user record has been created. When the user account gets created I need to update the `student_registration` table adding the new user id.

Is it the case that I just have this the wrong way around or should Rails handle this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have setup your associations the correct way, but I guess the implementation is wrong.

No problems, just go through this link and you'd be good to go.

[Nested-model-form-part-1 - Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Comment: Ok, I've just tried adding accepts_nested_attributes_for to my User model but still no joy. I'm thinking that what I'm doing is the wrong way around. Can the StudentRegistration Model update its foreign key attribute (user_id), when it doesn't know the user id until after the User has been created?

Comment: Yes, It can't. That's why we build a new `user` object and then call `user.student_registeration.build` and then pass this object to the view to be filled with inputs from the browser. I urge you to closely go through the link I have posted

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the correct path @Jatin. My issue was that I was looking at the controllers the wrong way around!